# Outlook for Mac allowing domains outside of the AppDomain

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

In Outlook for Mac when using an Office 365 Add-in, if my manifest does not contain the AppDomain element (foo.com), I would expect that navigating to a URL (foo.com/help.html) would result in opening the browser. However, when I open external links that are associated with my source location (foo.com/index.html), these links are opening in dialog boxes. This is not the case for the Windows desktop application or the Outlook Web application, which opens the URL in the default browser.

Comment: Could you tell us the Outlook version you're using? Have you signed up for Insider builds?

Comment: This was tested on version `16.16 (180812)` without insider builds, and `16.16 (180720)` with Insider builds, on High Sierra 10.13.4